# Truncate trailing digit of Card Prefix if 0-9 digits are present

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some records in my table like:

```
Prefix Column
...
54664300
54664301
54664302
54664303
546643040
546643041
546643042
546643043
546643044
546643045
546643046
546643047
546643048
546643049
54664305
54664306
54664307
54664308
54664309
...
54665100
54665101
54665102
54665103
54665105
54665106
54665109
...
```

If the 0-9 series are complete for a certain prefix, I simplify them. The following records above will become:

```
Prefix Column
...
54664300
54664301
54664302
54664303
54664304
54664305
54664306
54664307
54664308
54664309
...
54665100
54665101
54665102
54665103
54665105
54665106
54665109
...
```

And I can further simplify them because the 0-9 series has been completed. Which will result to:

```
Prefix Column
...
5466430
...
54665100
54665101
54665102
54665103
54665105
54665106
54665109
...
```

But some records will not get simplified because they are incomplete.

I achieved this process using `WHILE` loop:

```
DECLARE @length INT = (SELECT MAX(LEN(CardPrefix)) FROM #Card) - 1;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GroupedCard') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #GroupedCard;
CREATE TABLE #GroupedCard (CardPrefix NVARCHAR(20));

WHILE (@length > 6) -- minimum 6 digits only
BEGIN

    TRUNCATE TABLE #GroupedCard;

    INSERT INTO #GroupedCard
    SELECT LEFT(CardPrefix, @length) CardPrefix
        FROM #Card
        WHERE LEN(CardPrefix) > @length 
        GROUP BY LEFT(CardPrefix, @length)
        HAVING SUM(CAST(ISNULL(RIGHT(CardPrefix, 1), 0) AS INT)) = 45; --sum of 0 to 9 is 45

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #GroupedCard) BREAK; 

    DELETE #Card
        FROM #Card C
        INNER JOIN #GroupedCard GC ON GC.CardPrefix = LEFT(C.CardPrefix, 9);

    INSERT INTO #Card
    SELECT CardPrefix FROM #GroupedCard;

END
```

I am just checking if there is a more efficient way to do this because our records are getting huge in our live environment. There will also be a need to execute this process more frequently.

Comment: Isn't this just the 9 left digits and a `DISTINCT`? A `WHILE` *will* be a truly show way to do this.

Comment: It is like finding the common prefix with all the records present. Not all prefixes will be simplified, if they are not complete with the 0-9 series. Sorry I forgot to add example for this one.I have added just now.

Comment: So you want all values that are 9 characters long, and for those over 9 digits long, you want the left 9 digits and only the `DISTINCT` values?

Comment: Sorry if it is unclear. This is regardless of the length. My loop begins with the longest records and the process runs until length of 6, or if I cannot find any more records with complete 0-9 trailing series.

Answer (score 2):

Reading between the lines, but therefore are you not after...

```
SELECT Prefix
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE Prefix <= 99999999 --If this is alphanumeric, use LEN, but this will come at a cost
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(Prefix,8)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE Prefix > 99999999; --If this is alphanumeric, use LEN, but this will come at a cost
```